# Button click does not work in widget in newer versions of Android

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I created a Widget that contains a ViewFlipper and with buttons you can switch. Found a solution, applied it, everything works, but not in newer versions of Android. For example, in version API 24 (Android 7) it works fine, but in new ones, for example API 30, the widget does not handle clicks. Please help me figure out what the problem is.

```
package com.example.informationwidget.widgets.actual_info_widget

import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import com.example.informationwidget.R
import com.example.informationwidget.SettingsActivity
import com.example.informationwidget.services.LastCompaniesService


/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
class ActualInfoWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    private val WIDGET_LC_LEFT_BUTTON = "android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_LC_LEFT_BUTTON"
    private val WIDGET_LC_RIGHT_BUTTON = "android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_LC_RIGHT_BUTTON"
    private val WIDGET_LC_SETTINGS_BUTTON = "android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_LC_SETTINGS_BUTTON"
    private val WIDGET_LC_UPDATE_BUTTON = "android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_LC_UPDATE_BUTTON"

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)

        val v = intent!!.getIntExtra(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
        )

        val views = RemoteViews(context!!.packageName, R.layout.actual_info_widget)
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)

        val widgetName = ComponentName(context, ActualInfoWidget::class.java)
        val widgetId = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(widgetName)

//        Button click
        when {
            WIDGET_LC_LEFT_BUTTON == intent!!.action -> {
                Log.e("This is ViewFlipper:", "This is left button, id = " + v) //widgetId[0]
                views.showPrevious(R.id.vfLastChosenCompanies)
            }
            WIDGET_LC_RIGHT_BUTTON == intent.action -> {
                Log.e("This is ViewFlipper:", "This is right button, id = " + v)
                views.showNext(R.id.vfLastChosenCompanies)
            }
            WIDGET_LC_UPDATE_BUTTON == intent.action -> {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, widgetId[0])
            }
        }

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId[0], views)
    }

    private fun updateAppWidget(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetId: Int
    ) {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.actual_info_widget)
        val mainIntent = Intent(context, ActualInfoWidget::class.java)
        mainIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
        mainIntent.data = Uri.parse(mainIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))

        // Buttons from widget
        val pendingSettingsBtn = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickSettingsBtn(context), 0)

        val viewerIntentLeftClick = Intent(WIDGET_LC_LEFT_BUTTON)
        val viewerPendingLeftClick = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            viewerIntentLeftClick,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val viewerIntentRightClick = Intent(WIDGET_LC_RIGHT_BUTTON)
        val viewerPendingRightClick = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            viewerIntentRightClick,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val intentUpdateClick = Intent(WIDGET_LC_UPDATE_BUTTON)
        val pendingUpdateBtn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            intentUpdateClick,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        showLastCompanies(views, context, appWidgetId)
        Log.e("ID: ", appWidgetId.toString())

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnLcSettings, pendingSettingsBtn)
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnLeftScroll, viewerPendingLeftClick)
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnRightScroll, viewerPendingRightClick)
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnLcUpdate, pendingUpdateBtn)

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.lvLastCompanies)
    }

    private fun clickSettingsBtn(context: Context): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(context, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        intent.data = Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))

        return intent
    }

    private fun showLastCompanies(rv: RemoteViews, context: Context, appWidgetId: Int) {
        val adapter: Intent = Intent(context, LastCompaniesService::class.java)
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvLastCompanies, adapter)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using **implicit** broadcast. Just make sure that you make them all **explicit**.

For example:

```
val viewerIntentLeftClick = Intent(WIDGET_LC_LEFT_BUTTON)
ComponentName componentName = ComponentName(context, ActualInfoWidget::class.java);
viewerIntentLeftClick.setComponent(componentName);
```

Check out [limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) starting from Android N